# Slow graphics on ubuntu 17.10 on Macbook Pro 15 (late 2013)

Tags: 17.10, macbook-pro

I am experiencing slowdown when running Ubuntu 17.10 on my Macbook Pro 15" (late-2013) with the following specifications:

Memory: 8 GiB
Processor: Intel® Core™ i7-4750HQ CPU @ 2.00GHz × 8
Graphics: Intel® Haswell Mobile
GNOME: 3.26.2
OS type" 64-bit

More details on the slowdown:

1. There are delays when entering data and the data is displayed on the screen.
2. When playing regular movies, the pictures load slowly.
3. Regular simulations and animations run much slower than they do in the ubuntu 16.04.

Any ideas what might fix the problem?

```
$ lspci -nnk | grep -A3 -Fe '[0300]'
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Crystal Well Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0d26] (rev 08)
    Subsystem: Apple Inc. Crystal Well Integrated Graphics Controller [106b:012e]
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing the fan control daemon (**macfanctld**) for Macbook Pro solved the issue, s the CPU now doesn't 'panic' over the fan performance which varies with the temperature:

```
sudo apt-get install macfanctld
```

It was a quick and simple fix, wish someone had told me earlier! 
I hope this helps someone who uses macbook pro and runs into the same problem. Another experience was that the LTS versions of the Ubuntu have this functionality already embedded in them so you run in to this problem less often. Moreover, installing the macfanctld on LTS versions don't harm; so I strongly recommend using it for anyone considering installing ubuntu on a macbook!